# How can I access the new javascript keyword from scala.js?

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I am porting a JavaScript library to Scalajs. The JS Objects are created with the new keyword on the JavaScript side, so this is what I do in most cases.

```
trait Point extends js.Object {
  def normalize(length: Double): Point = js.native
}
```

This seems to work well for methods, however, this doesn't work for constructors.

```
@JSName("paper.Point")
object PointNative extends js.Object {
  def apply(props: RectProps): Rectangle = js.native
}
```

The above code does not work. It passes type checks and compiles, but at runtime it returns undefined.

If I modified PointNative like this then all is good.

```
import js.Dynamic.{ global => g, newInstance => jsnew }
object PointNative {
  def apply(props: RectProps): Rectangle = jsnew(g.paper.Point)(props).asInstanceOf[Point]
}
```

Is there a way to use @JSName and js.native with the new keyword?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, in the JavaScript API, `paper.Point` needs to be instantiated with the `new` keyword, you need to define PointNative as a class:

```
@JSName("paper.Point")
class PointNative(props: PointProps) extends js.Object {
  ...
}
```

which allows to instantiate it with

```
new PointNative(props)
```

just like you would have done in JavaScript.

If you also want to be able to instantiate it with just

```
PointNative(props)
```

then you need to define an additional, non-`js.Object` companion with an `apply()` method:

```
object PointNative {
  def apply(props: PointProps): PointNative = new PointNative(props)
}
```

Note that, if you need the companion `PointNative` to be a `js.Object` (because you also want to define static methods of `paper.Point` in it), then you can pimp `apply()` on it with an implicit class instead:

```
implicit class PointNativeCompanionOps(val self: PointNative.type) extends AnyVal {
  def apply(props: PointProps): PointNative = new PointNative(props)
}
```